# Fix JOLT config to get expected result

Tags: jolt

I receive JSON from API:

```
[
   {
      "date":"2023-08-15",
      "params":[
         {
            "id":"3877",
            "available":true,
            "tag": "podxmeil"
         },
         {
            "id":"559",
            "available":false,
            "tag": "kogdaeymtim"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "date":"2023-08-16",
      "params":[
         {
            "id":"327",
            "available":false,
            "tag": "syuopernuitd"
         },
         {
            "id":"916",
            "available":false,
            "tag": "tabgramidi"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to loop through `params` array and add values from it to top level
Tried with:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "date": "[&1].date",
        "params": {
          "*": {
            "id": "[&1].id",
            "available": "[&1].available"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But it stores values inside array and returns invalid result:

[image: f]

I Expect this result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following spec.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "params": {
          "*": {
            "@(2,date)": "&3.&1.date",
            "id": "&3.&1.&",
            "available": "&3.&1.&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: @takotsubo Mark this as an answer if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain  `"@(2,date)": "[&3].&3_&1.date"`? I don't cleary understand these indexes

Comment: "@(2,data)" means to go 2 levels up and grab the date value. [&3] is the arrey index from the current position. &3_&1 is just to group the values under the index.

Comment: Try to execute one-by-one operations. So you can understand what is happening in each phase.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thank you for your suggestions. I'm just learning Jolt from your previous answers. Glad to get suggestions from you. Will update the answer as suggested.